# CSS issue in UCWeb browser

Tags: android, html, css

I'm from Iran. I have a problem with my site view in UCWeb browser.
My site working perfectly on all browsers except UCWeb!
If browser set to "Fit to screen" mode, Site's Css look like doesn't work but when that set to "Zoom View" everything working perfectly.
It seems CSS not loading in "Fit To Screen" mode.
Any idea to help me?

Zoom View
[image]

Fitted To Screen view
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: try this in html header
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: You awesome! I tried this code but without "user-scalable=no". problem solved. mamnonam!

Comment: your welcome, so add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in html header**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

have fun